# xarray - Use groupby to group by every day over a year's climatological hourly netCDF data

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a hourly netCDF climatological data for a geographic extent over a year, e.g. from `2017-01-01T00:00:00` to `2017-12-31T23:00:00`.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 106, longitude: 193, time: 8760)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 ... 2017-12-31T23:00:00
Data variables:
    T_SFC      (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<shape=(8760, 106, 193), chunksize=(744, 106, 193)>
Attributes:
    creationTime:        1525708833
    creationTimeString:  Mon May  7 09:00:32 PDT 2018
    Conventions:         COARDS
```

As the it says well, the data has three coords (lat, lng and time) and a variable being hourly temperature.

My code:

```
import xarray as xr
mds_temp_path = '../Archive/*/IDV71000_VIC_T_SFC.nc'    # netCDF
mds_temp = xr.open_mfdataset(mds_temp_path)    # open netCDF and read into a dataset object

print(mds_temp.groupby('time.dayofyear').mean('time'))
```

What I got:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (dayofyear: 365, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
  * dayofyear  (dayofyear) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 359 360 361 362 363 364 365
Data variables:
    T_SFC   (dayofyear, latitude, longitude) float64 dask.array<shape=(365, 106, 193), chunksize=(1, 106, 193)>
```

What I would like to achieve to be able to get a mean temperature value for every day, e.g. the time coordinate in the generated dataset being "2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", ... ..., "2017-12-31", instead of 1, 2, 3, ... ..., 365.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [`resample`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html#xarray.Dataset.resample) method instead of [`groupby`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.groupby.html#xarray.Dataset.groupby):

```
mds_temp.resample(time='1D').mean()
```

These concepts are more fully described in the time series data section in the documentation: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#resampling-and-grouped-operations

Answer (score 1):

Using @jhamman's answer is useful, but if there is a missing day in between your measurements, the method `resample(...)` will fill it, see this example:

```
# create a dataset with data on days 1 & 3
t = ['2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-01T01:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-01T02:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-03T01:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-03T02:00:00.000000000']
t = pd.to_datetime(t)
ds = xr.Dataset({"foo": ("time", np.arange(len(t))), "time": t})

# reduce to days (but with interpolation on day 2!)
ds = ds.resample(time='1D').mean()
print(ds.time)

<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 3)>
array(['2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2000-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 2000-01-03
```

In my case, I didn't want this behavior, missing days must remain missing after the aggregation by day, so I use this approach:

```
# set all dates to have time at 00h so multiple measurements in a day have the same label
ds.coords['time'] = ds.time.dt.floor('1D')

# group by 'date' using an average (mean)
ds = ds.groupby('time').mean()

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 2)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-03
Data variables:
    foo      (time) float64 1.0 4.0

print(ds)

# set all dates to have time at 00h so multiple measurements in a day have the same label
ds.coords['time'] = ds.time.dt.floor('1D')

# group by 'date' using an average (mean)
ds = ds.groupby('time').mean()

print(ds)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 2)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-03
Data variables:
    foo      (time) float64 1.0 4.0
```

I hope it can be helpful for someone :)